# Image is not showing on my html page, using but only a link (path to image)

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, django

I have created an HTML(dashboard.html) page containing a div to display newly registered users' names, registration dates, and the user's pictures.
div shows user names, and registration dates, but not the user's picture. Here is just a link to the image: [image]

**Here are the files and their contents:
podcast_user.models.py**:

```
class PodcastUser(AbstractUser):
    user_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=30,unique=True)
    phone_regex = RegexValidator(regex=r'^\+?1?\d{9,15}$',message="Phone number must be in the format: '+999999999'. Up to 15 digits allowed.")
    phone_number = models.CharField(validators=[phone_regex], max_length=17, blank=True, null=True, unique=True, default='+')
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    date_of_join = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True,default=date.today)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True, null=True)
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='user_images/', blank=True, null=True)
    city_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    postal_code = models.CharField(max_length=10,blank=True, null=True)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=30,
                          validators=[RegexValidator(regex="^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.["r"a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$",
                                                     message='please enter the correct format')],unique=True)
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name', 'last_name','username']

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        if self.filter(is_superuser=True).exists():
            raise ValueError('Superuser already exists')
        # set some default values for the superuser
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)

        # create the superuser with the provided email and password
        return self._create_user(email=email, password=password, **extra_fields)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.username} ({self.user_id})"
```

**podcast_user.views.py:**

```
 def PodcastDashboard(request):
     thirty_days_ago = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=30)
     new_users = PodcastUser.objects.filter(date_of_join__gte=thirty_days_ago)
     return render(request, 'pages/podcast_dashboard.html', {'new_users': new_users})
```

**podcast_user.urls.py:**

```
 from django.urls import re_path,path
 from .views import login_and_register,PodcastDashboard,logout_view,confirm_user_request

 urlpatterns = [
     re_path(r'^login_and_register/', login_and_register, name='login_and_register'),
     re_path(r'^podcast_dashboard/', PodcastDashboard, name='podcast_dashboard'),
     re_path(r'^logout/', logout_view, name='logout'),
     path('confirm_user_request/<int:user_id>/', confirm_user_request, name='confirm_user_request'),
 ]
```

**podcast.urls.py:**

```
 from django.contrib import admin
 from django.urls import include, re_path,path
 from django.views.generic import TemplateView
 from django.conf.urls.static import static
 from podcast.settings.base import MEDIA_URL, MEDIA_ROOT

 urlpatterns = [
     re_path(r'^admin', admin.site.urls),
     re_path(r"^user/", include('podcast_user.urls')),
     re_path(r"^", TemplateView.as_view(template_name="pages/home.html"), name="home"),

 ]+ static(MEDIA_URL, document_root=MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**podcast_dashboard.html:**

```
 {% load static %}
 {% if user.is_authenticated %}
 {% block content %}
 <div class="card-body p-0">
   <h1>New Registered Users</h1>
     <ul class="users-list clearfix">
        {% for user in new_users %}
          <li>
            {% if user.image %}
               <img src="{{ user.image.url }}" >
            {% endif %}
            <a class="users-list-name" href="#">{{ user.first_name }} {{ user.last_name }}</a>
            <span class="users-list-date"> {{ user.date_of_join|date:"M d, Y" }}</span>
          </li>
         {% empty %}
            <li>No new registered users.</li>
          {% endfor %}
       </ul>
     </div>
 {% endblock %}
 {% endif %}
```

Here is finale result:
[image]

```
stractur:
podcast
|
├── podcast_user
|
└── templates_static_media
    ├── media
    |   └── user_images
    |       ├── default.jpg
    |       ├── dream_TradingCard.jpg
    |       ├── dream_TradingCard_1.jpg
    |       ├── Podcast-ddddd.png
    |       
    ├── static
    └── templates
        └── pages
            ├── podcast_dashboard.html
            └── test.htm
```

**and settings.py:**

```
ROOT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))
APPS_DIR = os.path.join(ROOT_DIR, "templates_static_media/")
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
STATIC_URL = "static/"
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
"django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder",
"django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder",
)
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(APPS_DIR, "static/"),)
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'django.core.files.storage.FileSystemStorage'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(APPS_DIR, "/media/")
MEDIA_URL = "/media/"
```

***when I use path in URLs, it is working fine, but when I change path to re_path image will not display.***

Comment: what is the rendered image url (... src=" ..." ) if you look at the page source code in the browser?

Comment: src="/media/user_images/dream_TradingCard_1.jpg"

Comment: Either the path is wrong or you forget to serve the images at all

Comment: please check if MEDIA_ROOT + /user_images/xxx.jpg is the correct path like "d:/ ....." and the jpg is there

Comment: I add a structure path up

Comment: what does print(settings.MEDIA_ROOT) return?

Comment: It is displaying C:/media/